# unable to connect as sysdba on remote oracle db from local system

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Hi im trying to connect as sysdba to remote server oracle db from local system sql plus
Im getting

```
Ora-01031: insufficient previleges
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Typically this means your user doesn't have the SYSDBA privilege; unless you're the DBA, this is unsurprising.

Comment: This question has the most obvious solution and answer, therefore I'm not going to migrate it to serverfault. The problem is that the user account you're connecting with does not have the required privileges (hence the error message.) The solution: Connect with a user that has the required privileges, or give the user the required privileges. Either way, this question is being closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to connect as SYS user to a remote DB, you'll have to set a password first using the **orapwd** utility (see http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/50344/0/ for an example).

Comment: Hi oracle db is on server, if i run the following cmnd local system, pwdfile will be created on server.? orapwd file=$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapwsid password=secure entries=5. how to create pwd file on server.

Comment: You have to run orapwd on the server.

Comment: i donot have permission to connect to server. Is there any way i can create from local using remote hostname, user name,PWd and service name. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is no way - you'll have to ask the system administrator to setup the password for you.